# How to insert Google Analytics after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to insert Google Analytics snippet after clicking a button, and therefore counting it as a visit.

Is it possible to do without needing to reload the page?

Comment: Would [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy) be useful?

Comment: @Jaxo could you post a simple example please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the Analytics code into a variable.

Then append it to the `head` tag when the button is clicked.

```
ga = "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){" +
     "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o)," +
     "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)" +
     "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');" +
     "ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');" +
     "ga('send', 'pageview');"

$('a.button').on('click', function() {
  $('head').append('<script>' + ga + '</script>');
});
```

Comment: This is not working if you use inline javascript (embedded in the html-page), because the script-tags will be parsed and it therefore leads to an javascript error; in this case, use the above mentioned  way with document.createElement("script"); seems to be more legit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy), namely `trackPageView` (found on [David Walsh's site](http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics)]:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'url-to-track.html']);
```

On a button:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //Button click event
  alert("Tracking pageview");
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'url-to-track.html']);
}, false);
```

```html
<button>Track me!</button>
```

In response to your comment:

```js
var js = 'document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick=function(){alert("I\'m loaded!");}';

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  //Uncomment this and put the path for your file
  //script.src = "path/to/script.js";

  //Remove this, this is just for the demo
  script.innerHTML = js;

  document.body.appendChild(script);
  alert("Appended script, click the button again");
};
```

```html
<button>Load a JS file</button>
<p>Or in this case, a string</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is it possible to load the Analytics code? (not just the track page view, but the entire code).

Comment: I suppose you could manually add the script tag to the page using Javascript, the same way normal Javascript injection works.  You could save the GA code in a small .js file, then use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [document.body.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to add the script.