# How to insert dynamic tracking pixel after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, analytics, pixel, tracking, matomo

I am referring to this question, that has been solved, but only is part of the solution I am looking for:
[How to insert Google Analytics after clicking a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590195/how-to-insert-google-analytics-after-clicking-a-button)

I want to use a dynamic tracking code from a database, after a button is clicked. The use case is an opt-in plugin (for Wordpress). The actual tracking code comes from the database. It will be queried by PHP and only executed after the user gives the confirmation.

This is my code, so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function( $ ) {

        $("#button").click(function(){

            var pixel = <?php echo $pixel; ?>;

            $('head').append('<script>' + pixel + '</script>');

        });

    })( jQuery );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question and struggling around I found the solution for myself:

First thing that is wrong is the script-Tags, mentioned in the linked question. If I use inline JavaScript it will be parsed and the browser will throw an error. But I need inline JavaScript because I need to query the tracking pixel with PHP. So I have to create a Script-Element like this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
```

Next thing is the usage of special chars like line breaks, carriage returns and quotes. So one may not just echo the tracking pixel, it will lead to parsing errors, too, because the tracking pixel most certainly contains line breaks and quotes. So in PHP I need to replace them. The most simple way would be:

```
var pixel = '<?php echo (str_replace("\n", "", str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("'", "\"", $pixel)))); ?>';
```

So, the final and working code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function( $ ) {

        $("#button").click(function(){

            var pixel = '<?php echo (str_replace("\n", "", str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("'", "\"", $pixel)))); ?>';

            var script = document.createElement("script");

            script.innerHTML = pixel;

            document.body.appendChild(script);

        });

    })( jQuery );

</script>
```